# The resource at (url) was blocked due to its Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy header (or lack thereof)

Tags: express, http-headers

I am trying to display images with an `src` coming from external APIs like google or `flagsapi` to my html file served as a static file from my express application, but I keep getting this error:

```bash
The resource at (url) was blocked due to its Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy header (or lack thereof).
```

I already tried changing my CORP header to `cross-origin` with this code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy', 'cross-origin')
    next()
})
```

The error still persists after this code was added. I cannot find any solution on the internet for this problem.